# Cannot get submenu to hover under parent menu through CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

HTML beginner here!

I'm creating a menu navigation where the user would hover over the selection and a menu would appear directly under it.

I have managed to get it to appear when hovered over but all the submenus stick to one corner of the site like this: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EyUQ.png)
[and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sh6W.png) (Apologises for the awful layout thus far, haven't begun to think on colour schemes yet!) I have also tried display:inline-block but it makes the submenu appear to the right of it.

Here is the HTML and CSS that I have for the menu so far.

All help and pointers will be greatly appreciated! :)

HTML

```
    <ul class="hoverMenu">
      <li><a href="info.html">Information</a>
         <ul>
         <li><a href="info.html#location">Location</a></li>
         <li><a href="info.html#travel">Travel</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="timetable.html">Timetable</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
        <li><a href="dances.html">Dances</a></li>
        <li><a href="meals.html">Meals</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="dances.html">Dance List</a></li>
      <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a ></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    #navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px double #19b2db;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    color: #001240;
}
    #navigation li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
    ul.hoverMenu, ul.hoverMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: positive;
}
    ul.hoverMenu ul {
    display: none; /*initially menu item is hidden*/;
    position: absolute; /*absolute positioning is important for menu to float*/;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0;
}
    ul.hoverMenu li:hover > ul {
    /* Hover effect for menu*/   
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `#navitation li`. And remove `position: positive;` from `ul.hoverMenu, ul.hoverMenu ul`.

Comment: Just exactly how I wanted this to work! Thank you so much for this :)